# What does the method call output?

Tags: java

Im having trouble understanding this piece of code from class. The answer is 3 but I don't understand why. Wouldnt it be 2 since there is only one "e" in the string which would add 1 to z?

```
myMethod("Karel The Dog", 'e');


public int myMethod(String x, char y) {     
    int z = 1;   
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
        if(x.charAt(i) == y) {
            z++;
        }
    }
    return z;
}
```

Comment: You need to set the init value of `z` to **0**

Comment: *since there is only one "e"* - er no, there is two `e` chars

Comment: it's Kar**e**l Th**e** Dog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int z = 1` plust two `e` (one in `karEl` and another one in `thE`) in the string equals `3`.

To count required characters, do inti counter with `0`:

```
public static int myMethod(String str, char ch) {
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        if (str.charAt(i) == ch)
            total++;

    return total;
}
```